# UITableView doesn't show up in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've created a view with a `UIScrollView`, it has height 1000px. I've added a `UITableView` to the view, plus other labels and buttons. When I launch it, everything is in its place except the table. Can anyone fix my problem?

I've tried:

```
table.hidden = NO;
```

and

```
[scrollView addSubview:table];
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: has the table any data ?

Comment: Also, what's the tables frame?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `UITableView` please. This is nothing to go.

Comment: Did you connect the delegate and data source of the table to the file owner in IB? Try connecting those if you haven't.

Comment: a tableview shouldnt be inside a scrollview :/

Comment: the table has data and I connected the delegate and data source. I'll try the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `UIScrollView` specifically says not to do this:

> **Important**: You should not embed `UIWebView` or `UITableView` objects in `UIScrollView` objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

I would suggest adding the other views you intend to put into the scroll view into the table as a `tableHeaderView`, `tableFooterView`, or as custom cells.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I only wanted to display data as a static table (without any touch events) to scroll down with other labels. I will try and let You know.